# Unable to pass reference of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a website where a User can keep track of which vaccinations their pets have recieved. That also mean that every vaccination should have a reference to the pet having recieved the vaccination.

**Pet**

```
public class Pet{
    public int AnimalId {get; set;}
    public string AnimalName{get; set;}
    public AnimalType Type {get; set;}
    public bool IsNeutered {get; set;}
}
```

**Vaccine**

```
public class Vaccine{
    public int VaccineId{get; set;}
    public string VaccineName{get; set;}
    public Pet Pet{get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, the Vaccine-class contain a reference to Pet. And everything worked fine.

But now i found out that i dont want the owners to add the vaccinations themselves. Instead i want a Doctor (admin), to create these Vaccines and then let the users add the vaccine through a dropdown.

But since the vaccination contain a reference to Pet, the doctor can't create a Vaccine because the Doctor doesn't have a reference of a Pet to pass. And the Pet-variable is non-nullable.

What is the right way to go about this? Should i add a List of Vaccines to the Pet instead like so:

```
public virtual List<Vaccine> VaccineList {get; set;}
```

Comment: Why can't you just make the User pass the Pet reference to the Doctor? Surely the owners of the pets must have some way of identifying them. When they select which vacine they want the doctor to apply they should also select which pet they want to be vaccinated, after all they might have more than 1 pet.

Comment: @Lucas Not exactly, because you should think of it like this. A new Vaccine comes to market and the Doctor wants to add it to the system, but doesnt necessarily want to give the vaccine to a pet.

Comment: If that's your train of thought there's no point in having a Pet property on Vaccine. Vaccines aren't made to be used on one specific pet. As another user answered, it makes more sense to have Vaccine and Vaccination as separate classes. You could also use Vaccination to correlate Vaccines to Pets, similar to how a many-to-many relationship works on relational databases

Comment: @Lucas, As i also wrote to Pepito in the answer below, I appologize for the bad wording. I dont necessarily want to keep track of the vaccinations only what vaccines are given to the Pet. So having a List<Vaccine> in the Pet-class should do the trick. Thanks a lot for your answer! It cleared up my mind :)

Comment: @Lucas I would have given you points for your answers if possible. But since im a brand new user, I'm not allowed until I recieve 15 points or more - hope you understand.

Comment: You know what you want to do with your program better than I do, but it might be worth pointing out that some pet vaccines have expirations times andneed to be reaplied from time to time, while others require multiple dosages to be effective. Having vaccination records to record when each vaccine was applied would help deal with cases like these. No need to worry about the points though :)

Comment: I like you thoughts. However, this is really just a matter of improving my programming-skills, so i just find it interresting to make smaller systems for now. But when I "finish it", i think it will be a good practice to improve on my working system... Kinda gives me a new set of problems than if i started from the bottom. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are missing a class: the Vaccine itself. Pets should have a list of vaccinations: when and what they received.

Pet

```
public class Pet{
    public int AnimalId {get; set;}
    public string AnimalName{get; set;}
    public AnimalType Type {get; set;}
    public bool IsNeutered {get; set;}
    public List<Vaccination> Vaccinations {get; set;}
}
```

Vaccine

```
public class Vaccine{
    public int VaccinationId{get; set;}
    public string VaccinationName{get; set;}
}
```

Vaccination

```
public class Vaccination{
    public Vaccine Vaccine{get; set;}
    public DateTime VaccinedAt{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I appologize for my english. It might have been a bad wording to use "Vaccination" and not just use "Vaccine". I dont really need to keep track of when the Pet recieved the vaccine. So really all i need it to keep track of what vaccines the pet recieved.

But i think that you somewhat answered my question anyway. I should add
public virtual List<Vaccine> VaccineList {get; set;} to the Pet and remove Pet-refernce i the Vaccine-class.

Comment: Having a List<Vaccine> in Pet is probably gonna do the trick. Thank you for your time, it was of great help!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to break down your problem one by one :
"*I am trying to create a website where a User can keep track of which vaccinations their pets have received.*" - means the Pet class should have reference to list of Vaccination- not other way around. if you want to keep track of all the pets which took a particular  Vaccination, then you need to add a reference to a list of pet in Vaccination class

```
**List of Vaccination for a Pet**

public class Pet {
    public int AnimalId {get; set;}
    public string AnimalName{get; set;}
    public AnimalType Type {get; set;}
    public bool IsNeutered {get; set;}        
    public List<Vaccination> VaccineList {get; set;}
}
```

List of Pet took a Vaccination

```
public class Vaccine {
    public int VaccineId{get; set;}
    public string VaccineName{get; set;}
    public List<Pet> Pets{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have sadly already marked an Answer. But you are EXACTLY right. I cant give you any points either, because since im a new User i need at least 15 point to upvote an answer. - Hope you understand.

Comment: @CodeQuest no issues . Hope i was able to help you :)

Comment: Most definitely!